# Count rows with same values in specific column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, count, rows

I have a csv file containing many products (40k) and many columns with price,category,name...
I want to count how many rows (products) are there in each category (taking them directly from the file) and display it.
How can i do this using pandas? Or is it better to use something else?

Comment: Pandas can probably be used for this. have you tried anything yet? Your question is quite general, perhaps you can add some of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I've tried the answer to this question and it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV, usecols=['category','products'])
print(df.groupby(['category']).count())
```

The first line creates a dataframe with two columns(categories and products) and the second line prints out the number of products in each category.

Comment: Thank you very much